# Can we improve this question title (Salon worker problem)?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, editing, edit-request

This question ([Salon worker problem](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/88820/3192)) is currently an advice question, but there seems to be an on-topic question in it, related to the owner's system of scheduling work for the employees, the employees' own preferences (along with some interpersonal/motivational issues) and the customers' preferences.

The current question title does not describe the issue at all, and does not help searchability. However, I could not phrase a proper question out of the description. Can someone with better skills please see if the question title can be improved?

The description could also do with some improvement of formatting, spelling and grammar, as well as fluff removal. I don't prefer doing half-complete edits, so decided not to do it myself.

Comment: I submitted an edit: Rotation of Stylists at a Salon. What do you think? Still does not embody the question wholly, but starts to get at the heart of the problem, yes?

Comment: @Teacher Thanks, it is certainly a significant step in the right direction. I will remove some of the fluff from the question in the coming days when I feel like it.

Comment: I am (again) pleasantly surprised by what the community edits did to the question: *Ensuring fair distribution of clients in a commission work environment* is a 100x better title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The title has now been updated to:

> Ensuring fair distribution of clients in a commission work environment

This is a fantastic improvement, as it describes the issue clearly, applies to more generic situations, and more searchable.

The fluff from the description has also been removed, so I consider this done!

**Thanks, [Teacher KSHuang](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/62982/teacher-kshuang), [sleske](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/57/sleske) and [Myles](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/26235/myles), for your efforts!**